# How to add styles in google organisation charts using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, google-visualization

I am trying to implement an organisation chart using google charts api. I am currently challenged in styling the organisation chart.

Current Chart:
https://imgur.com/tLLcP6u

I want to get something like this one:
https://imgur.com/cOefqb9

So far i have managed to get the data to be displayed.

The html div:
    `<div>
            <div google-chart chart="orgChartObj" class="global-main-back-div" style="padding-bottom:15px;"  id="chart_div"></div>
</div>`

The controller:

```
##The data structure
$scope.orgChartObj = {
  "type": "OrgChart",
//   "displayed": false,
  "data": {
    "cols" : [
          {"label": "id", "pattern": "", "type": "string"},
          {"label": "manager", "pattern": "", "type": "string"}
      ],
    "rows" : []
  },
  "formatters": {},
  "view": {}
}; 

//Users Data
$scope.users = [
{_id: "5c7e8cdf3d3e7ddc5f4ceadd", fullName: "T01"}

];
$scope.getLMs = function(){

    $scope.users.forEach(function(user){

        var row = {"c": [
                      {"v": "", "f": ""},
                      {"v": ""}
                  ]};
        row.c[0].v = user._id;
        row.c[0].f = user.fullName  +"<div style='color:red; font-style:italic'>Vice President</div>";

        $scope.orgChartObj.data.rows.push(row);



    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In the chart data structure I added

```
**'allowHtml': true** property 


$scope.orgChartObj = {
  "type": "OrgChart",
//   "displayed": false,
  "data": {
    "cols" : [
          {"label": "id", "pattern": "", "type": "string"},
          {"label": "manager", "pattern": "", "type": "string"}
      ],
    "rows" : []
  },
  "formatters": {},
  "view": {},
  "options": {
       'allowHtml': true
 }
};
```